# Como pedir ao usuário que crie um vetor np.array?

Tags: python, array, numpy

Gostaria de saber COMO é possível escrever um programa que leia um vetor array numpy `np.array([])` criado pelo usuário.

Em listas, por exemplo, fazemos:

```
n = int(input("Determine o número elementos da lista: "))
i = 0
lista = []
while i < n:
  elemento = int(input("Digite os elementos da lista: "))
  i += 1
  lista.append(elemento)
print(lista)
```

No caso dos vetores nummpy array, como isso seria feito sem que eu tenha que escrever um programa que primeiro receba uma lista do usuário e depois faça:`vetor = np.array([lista])`?

Tem como escrever um programa que permita que o usuário faça seu próprio vetor?

Answer (score 0):

Import do numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

Criando o np array

```
a = np.array([])
```

Adicionando elementos, você pode fazer isso com while, com um input somente e mapeando as entradas, aqui segue um exemplo com o for:

```
for i in range(5):
    a = np.append(a, float(input('n: ')), axis = None)
```

*Você pode alterar o casting para inteiro, caso seja somente números inteiros.*

Entrada:

```
n: 1
n: 2
n: 3
n: 4
n: 5
```

Saída:

```
print(a)
[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
```

Tipo do objeto:

```
type(a)
numpy.ndarray
```